# Trying to run app (fceux) on Linux beta

Tags: linux, chrome-book

I have a Chromebook and have downloaded Linux beta to it. I'm trying to run `fceux` (Ubuntu version) https://fceux.com/web/download.html. I've been able to download it with Linux but whenever I open the app it just loads infinitely. I tried opening it in the terminal and I get this response:

```
fceux: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version GLIBC_2.29 not found (required by fceux)
fceux: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version Qt_5.12 not found (required by fceux)
```

I've ran `sudo apt-get update` a lot but that hasn't helped. Also I tried to download `libc6_2.31-12_amd64` as a linux application but when I try it says:

```
WARNING: You are trying to remove the following essential packages: libc-bin.
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the highest version of GLIBC for Ubuntu 18.04 should be 2.27. You have three options essentially:

1. use another OS - ubuntu 19.04 and onwards seems to use the 2.3X library
2. add the testing repo and install from there **(I wouldn't recommend this unless it's a completely fresh install, testing repos can break your system!)**:

   ```
   echo "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && apt-get install build-essential -y
   ```
3. compile glibc 2.30 manually from source:

   - make a build directory

     ```
     mkdir build && cd build
     ```
   - pull desired version from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/ - 2.30 is [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.30.tar.gz)

     ```
     wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.30.tar.gz
     ```
   - untar package

     ```
     tar -xzvf glibc-2.2.4.tar.gz
     ```
   - Change to the glibc directory

     ```
     cd glibc-2.3.0
     ```
   - configure to generate makefile (you can specify any specific requirements you need here - [see this for more details](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Configuring-and-compiling.html)

     ```
     ./configure
     ```
   - and compile it:

     ```
     make
     ```

Regarding qt_5.12 - this should do the trick:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt-5.12.0-bionic
apt-get install qt512-meta-minimal -y
```

see [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebeineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt-5.12.0-bionic) for details on qt

Comment: The OP is not running Debian. Wrong assumptions are exactly the problem here which got us in the situation. Realizing that we are running another distribution which has a maintained package would at worst have resulted in a useful bug report and at best just a pleasant experience with a maintained package.

Answer (score 0):

You are not running Ubuntu. **You are running Debian!**

You do not need to download anything from any other site, even if it is the projects home page, because the package is in [the repositories](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/fceux) of your Debian distribution.

```
sudo apt-get install fceux
```

When you are more experienced with Linux you can go hunting 3rd party packages and other software. In the meantime [don't break Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian)!